# Instance of Firefox WebDriver is not created with selenium python bindings

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I installed selenium-python bindings and trying to create an instance of firefox web driver
as below

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I dont know whats wrong here and its displaying the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 44, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.21.3-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 81, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: cannot open display: :1100\n'
```

Can any please let me know how to solve this ..............

Answer (score 1):

The error says"cannot open display: :1100".  Are you running it on a remote terminal?  Make sure you can type "firefox" at the prompt and have the browser open (that is what Webdriver does - opens Firefox on your system and then trying to connect to it). If you are running it on a remote system, do a web search on connecting to X display remotely.